# How to rewrite this SQL query using Rails 3 finders method?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want rewrite this SQL query :

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, p.gender, (p.work_done/p.work_total * 100) r1, (p.work_success/p.work_total * 100) r2, p.StartTime, p.EndTime 
FROM Persons p 
WHERE p.id= params[:id] 
AND p.gender = params[:gender]
ORDER BY r1 desc
GROUP BY p.gender
```

Using latest rails 3 finder method (e.g. `where, select, group, order`....)

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
@list = Persons.select("id, name, gender, (work_done/work_total * 100) r1, (work_success/work_total * 100) r2, StartTime, EndTime").where("id = ? AND gender = ?", params[:id],  params[:gender]).order("r1 desc").group("name")
```

Any idea where I do it wrong?

EDIT:
Previously I used this :

```
@list = Persons.find_by_sql("same sql code above").group_by {|t| t.name}
```

in my view:

```
<% @list.each do |person, person_list| %>
```

....

And it worked, but I when I try to use the finder method it says:

```
(undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass)
```

and give me this error when querying the database:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 280ms
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message or the wrong result?

Comment: I am getting this error: "Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 280ms"

Comment: What is the error in your server log or when you run this in the console? This will be a lot more specific than Internal Server Error.

Comment: You wrote `Persons`. Is your model name really plural?

Comment: Yes, I make it this way intentionally :), but I don't think that's the cause

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
@list = Persons.select("id, name, gender, (work_done/work_total * 100) r1, (work_success/work_total * 100) r2, StartTime, EndTime").where("testrun_id = ? AND gender = ?", params[:id],  params[:gender]).order("r1 desc").group("gender")
```

Comment: Sorry for the typo! testrun_id should be id in the original post.